# Python Overwrite Dictionary to Text File doesn't work... why?

Tags: python, dictionary, interface, buffer, python-idle

I've been previously writing code for a quiz program with a text file that stores all of the participants' results. The code that converts the text file to a dictionary and the text file itself are shown below:

Code:

```
import collections
from collections import defaultdict
scores_guessed = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.deque(maxlen=4))
with open('GuessScores.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name,val = line.split(":")
        scores_guessed[name].appendleft(int(val))

for k in sorted(scores_guessed):
    print("\n"+k," ".join(map(str,scores_guessed[k])))

writer = open('GuessScores.txt', 'wb')

for key, value in scores_guessed.items():       
    output = "%s:%s\n" % (key,value)
    writer.write(output)
```

The text file appears like this:

```
Jack:10
Dave:20
Adam:30
Jack:40
Adam:50
Dave:60
Jack:70
Dave:80
Jack:90
Jack:100
Dave:110
Dave:120
Adam:130
Adam:140
Adam:150
```

Now, when I run the program code, the dictionary appears like this:

```
Adam 150 140 130 50

Dave 120 110 80 60

Jack 100 90 70 40
```

Now, this arranges the dictionary into order of highest scores, and the top 4 scores!

I want the python IDLE to overwrite the GuessScores.txt to this:

```
Adam:150
Adam:140
Adam:130
Adam:50
Dave:120
Dave:110
Dave:80
Dave:60
Jack:100
Jack:90
Jack:70
Jack:40
```

BUT when I run the code, this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ahmad/Desktop/Test Files SO copy/readFile_prompt.py", line 16, in <module>
    writer.write(output)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

The GuessScores.txt file is empty because it cannot write to the file, since there is the error above.

Why is this happening? And what is the fix? I have asked this previously but there were numerous issues. I am running Python 3.3.2 on a Mac 10.8 Mavericks iMac, if that makes any help.

Thanks, 
Delbert.

Comment: Duplicate of your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520067/python-write-to-text-file-dictionary-shows-incorrect-information please stop asking the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you are trying to write text to a file that you opened in binary mode. In 3.x, this will no longer work. "text" vs. "binary" used to mean very little (only affecting line-ending translation, so no difference at all on some systems). Now it means like what it sounds like: a file opened in text mode is one whose contents are to be treated like text with some specific encoding, and a file opened in binary mode is one whose contents are to be treated as a sequence of bytes.

Thus, you need `open('GuessScores.txt', 'w')`, not `open('GuessScores.txt', 'wb')`.

That said, you really should be using `with` blocks to manage the files, and you're going to have to write code that actually formats the dictionary content in the way you want. I assume you intend to output in sorted name order, and you need to iterate over each deque and write a line for each item. Something like:

```
with open('GuessScores.txt', 'w') as f:
    for name, scores in sorted(scores_guessed.items()):
        for score in scores:
            f.write("{}:{}\n".format(name, score))
```

(Note also the new-style formatting.)

If necessary, you can explicitly specify the encoding of the file in the `open` call, with the `encoding` keyword parameter. (If you don't know what I mean by "encoding", you ***must*** learn. I'm serious. Drop everything and look it up.)

Comment: Isn't the last line of that block meant to be `scores_guessed.write("{}:{}\n".format(name, score))`

Comment: You're trying to write out to a file.  The file is opened as `f` in line 1.  You have to write to the file, not the dictionary of scores guessed.

Answer (score 0):

The writing problem has to do with the `b` in your `open` function. You've opened it in binary mode, so only bytes can be written. You can either remove the `b` or call `bytes` on `output` to give it the right type. You have a logic error anyway though. When I run it on Python 2.7, the output to GuessedScores.txt is this:

> Dave:deque([120,110,80,60],maxlen=4)
>    Jack:deque([100, 90, 70, 40], maxlen=4)
>    Adam:deque([150, 140, 130, 50], maxlen=4)

So your values are the whole deques, not the individual scores. You'll have to format them, similar to how you did in your print statement.