# Python Write to Text File Dictionary Shows incorrect information

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I'm currently testing my code to see if it functions properly, and therefore remove any inconsistencies.

First of all, the code is below:

```
user_name = str(input("What is your name?"))
last_name = str(input("What is your surname?"))
final_total = int(input("What is your total score?"))

with open('quiz_results.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name,val = line.split(":")
        user_scores[name].appendleft(int(val))

    with open("quiz_results.txt", "a+") as f:
        f.write('{}:{}\n'.format(user_name + last_name, final_total))
        print("complete.")

    with open('quiz_results.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            name,val = line.split(":")
            user_scores[name].appendleft(int(val))
```

Now, for test data, I added 'Dave' for the user_name, 'Johnson' for the last_name and final totals were 70, 80, 90 and 100 for each go, so I repeated the program 4 times.

When I type in the first result, 70, I get the result I expect in the text file:

```
DaveJohnson:70
```

Unusually enough, in the text file, when I type in 80 for the result (with the same name) I get in the text file:

```
DaveJohnson:80
DaveJohnson:70
DaveJohnson:70
```

when I should simply get:

```
DaveJohnson:80
DaveJohnson:70
```

When I type in 90, I get in the text file:

```
DaveJohnson:90
DaveJohnson:70
DaveJohnson:70
```

when I should simply get:

```
DaveJohnson:90
DaveJohnson:80
DaveJohnson:70
```

And When I type in 100, I get in the text file:

```
DaveJohnson:100
DaveJohnson:70
DaveJohnson:70
```

BUT I should get:

```
DaveJohnson:100
DaveJohnson:90
DaveJohnson:80
```

What on Earth is going wrong?
**Update** It is all solved.

Comment: Assuming your indentation is correct, it's not a good practice to write to a file while reading it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewriting my scores text file to make sure it only has the Last 4 scores (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507196/rewriting-my-scores-text-file-to-make-sure-it-only-has-the-last-4-scores-python)

Comment: The duplicate related to a separate issue at the time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

You are never clearing the `user_scores` dictionary before rereading the data to it (in the 3rd `with` statement)

Try to clear the dictionary before reading:

```
user_scores.clear() 
with open('quiz_results.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name,val = line.split(":")
        user_scores[name].appendleft(int(val))
```

Also: the last `with` statement does not look right; I guess you'd just want to write all name,score pairs like this:

```
with open('quiz_results.txt', 'wt') as f :
    for k, v in sorted(user_scores.items()):
        f.write(item[0] + ':' + str(item[1])+'\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading quizresults.txt twice without reseting the content of user_names. So if a user name/score pair is in the file at the start you read the score into user names, then read it in again. 
The content of user_scores looks like

start : `{'DaveJohnson':[]} #I'm guesing`

after first block on first run: `{'DaveJohnson':[]}`

after second block on first run: `{'DaveJohnson':[0]}`

after third block on first run: `{'DaveJohnson':[70]}`

after final block on first run: `{'DaveJohnson':[70]}`

after first block on second run: `{'DaveJohnson':[70]}`

after second block on second run: `{'DaveJohnson':[70]}` 
(here you append DaveJohnson:80 to your file

after third block on second run [here you re-read DaveJohnson:70 from the file and read DaveJohnson:80] : `{'DaveJohnson':[70,70,80]
Out of curiousity, why do you have one script that is reading to a file, appending to it, reading it again and then overwriting it?